# Насколько детально надо разбивать методы?

Tags: java, ооп, инспекция-кода

Спрошу на примере вот такого класса и его конструктора:

```
public class MultiDimensionalTop implements Comparable<MultiDimensionalTop> {

private ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> solutionOnTop = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> interestVars = new ArrayList<>(); 
private ArrayList<Long> limit = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Double> doubleVallist = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Integer> indexOfDoubleValList = new ArrayList<>();
private Task task;

public MultiDimensionalTop(Task task) {
    this.task = task;
    for (int i = 0; i < task.getLimitCount(); i++) {
        indexOfDoubleValList.add(-1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < task.getLimitCount(); i++) {
        doubleVallist.add(0.0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < task.getLimitCount(); i++) {
        interestVars.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }
    ArrayList<Boolean> tmpBool;
    for (int i = 0; i < task.getLimitCount(); i++) {
        tmpBool = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < task.getVarCount(); j++) {
            tmpBool.add(false);
        }
        solutionOnTop.add(tmpBool);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < task.getLimitCount(); i++) {
        limit.add(0L);
    }
}
```

Стоит ли циклы выносить в отдельные приватные методы `createDefaultXXXVakues()`?
Это поможет сделать каждый метод коротким и к тому же каждый метод будет выполнять свою задачу. Или можно рассмотреть с той точки зрения что конструктор и так не длинный и тоже в каком то смысле выполняет одну задачу - конструирование объекта.

Comment: Дублирование кода - это code smell. в вашем конструкторе можно было бы обойтись одним циклом

Comment: Ну это что сильнее. Либо лень написать дополнительно тройку строчек, либо не очень приятный вид.

Comment: Конечно, красота это субъективно, но на мой вкус такой код безобразен. Всю инициализацию надо делать в одном цикле.

Comment: @PashaPash, да, согласен, к ночи голова не соображает( Но все равно вопрос то остается актуальным. Нужно ли выносить этот один цикл в отдельный приватный метод? Или я слишком заморачиваюсь с тем что методы должны быть короткими и выполнять одну задачу?

Comment: @avp, да, конечно же, не знаю как я этого не заметил(

Answer (score 1):

Примерно вот так:

```
public MultiDimensionalTop(Task task) {
    this.task = task;
    int limitCount = task.getLimitCount()
    for (int i = 0; i < limitCount; i++) {

        indexOfDoubleValList.add(-1);
        doubleVallist.add(0.0);
        interestVars.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

        ArrayList<Boolean> tmpBool = new ArrayList<>();
        int varCount = task.getVarCount();
        for (int j = 0; j < varCount; j++) {
            tmpBool.add(false);
        }
        solutionOnTop.add(tmpBool);

        limit.add(0L);
    }
}
```

У вас ещё есть ошибка с тем, что вы объявляете переменную один раз вне цикла, а потом внутри цикла N раз присваиваете ей вновь создаваемый объект. Проблемы две:

- Это ничуть не экономит ресурсы, но запутывает код
- После последнего прохода цикла эта переменная остается доступна и с ней можно сделать что-нибудь нехорошее.

Объявляйте переменные только в том пространстве имен, где они нужны.

Comment: спасибо, тут я не прав конечно же, писал в попыхах этот код. Но все же это очень интересный для меня пример именно с точки зрения разбиения метода. Вот так как вы написали... нужно ли вынести цикл в отдельный приватный метод? Это же увеличит читабельность и структурированность кода?

Comment: @NiclVolynkin, а с tmpBool можно уточнить? Сделал как вы сказали и получил ошибку. Мне надо что бы каждый элемент solutionOnTop был разным массивом. Заполнены они должны быть одинаковы, но ссылки должны быть разные. Что бы изменения в одном элементе solutionOnTop не влияли на все другие. Что бы такое поведение обеспечить нужно же каждый раз присваивать новый объект, правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Я наброшу:

```
class SomethingThatLooksLikeRow {
    long limit = 0;
    double doubleVal = 0d;
    int someDoubleValIndex = -1;

    // это точно два разных списка, или это список пар?
    List<Integer> interestVars = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Boolean> solutionOnTop;

    public SomethingThatLooksLikeRow( int boolsSize ) {
        solutionOnTop = new ArrayList<>( Collections.nCopies( boolsSize, Boolean.FALSE ) );
    }
}

class MultiDimensionalTop implements Comparable<MultiDimensionalTop> {
    private List<SomethingThatLooksLikeRow> someRowsOfSomething;
    private Task task;

    public MultiDimensionalTop(Task task) {
        this.task = task;

        this.someRowsOfSomething = Stream.generate( () -> new SomethingThatLooksLikeRow(task.getVarCount()) )
            .limit( task.getLimitCount() )
            .collect( Collectors.toCollection( ArrayList::new ) );
    }
    /* here be dragons */
}
```

Comment: Считаете этот код понятней, чем был у ТС?

Comment: @avp Я предполагаю наличие связи между элементами с одним индексом у разных списков, и считаю, что эту связь лучше выразить, создав отдельный класс.

Comment: Но это же усложняет понимание кода. Первоначальный вариант (особенно после записи в одном цикле) абсолютно прозрачен с первого взгляда. А Ваш код требует некоторого времени для его понимания. Теперь представьте, в какой вариант новый программист внесет больше ошибок при изменении ТЗ?

Comment: Что именно будет изменять программист? Допустим, ему нужно будет добавить новый столбец. В варианте с рядом-объектом можно добавить поле, методы доступа по вкусу; возможно обновить конструктор, если поле значимо при создании. Компилятор покажет, где еще нужно вносить правки. В варианте с несколькими списками нужно будет править каждый метод, затрагивающий несколько списков (добавление/удаление элементов, сортировка). В ряд-объект можно перенести выражения, использующие несколько столбцов, и избавиться от `.get`. Один список лучше совместим с итераторами и Stream API (в api нет `zip`).

Comment: На мой взгляд Вы слишком увлекаетесь универсанилизацией изначально простой задачи (забываете KISS-принцип).

Comment: Задача, к сожалению, не озвучена целиком. Соглашусь, что код можно сократить: выкинуть конструктор и фабрику, вернуть создание списка булей обратно в `MultiDimensionalTop`, закрыть глаза и представить, что в яве есть `struct`.

Comment: @zRrr, вы абсолютно правы, у меня создается строка. Можно уточнить? Мораль вашего ответа в том, что если что то нужно раздробить - то нужно дробить? Если можно вынести часть кода в другой класс - выносить, если можно разбить большой метод на 2 маленьких - разбивать?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров Ваш вопрос: "У меня 5 списков длины N. Нужно ли мне их создавать в 5 циклах, и потом вынести эти циклы в 5 методов?". Мой ответ: "У вас 1 список записей/структур/объектов, разбивать его инициализацию на 5 частей - странно". Это вся мораль.

Answer (score 0):

Как правильно заметили в комментариях, имеет смысл сделать один внешний цикл до `task.getLimitCount()` и поместить всё в него.

Но если говорить про более общий случай, когда циклы разные, то ничего никуда выносить не надо, всё и так замечательно читается. Я бы только пустых строк между циклами добавил.